# Calling a fuction within a class is giving an error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class for creating events on a Google Calendar. I include this class in a screen where I can pick a date and enter the necessary data and set a date for the event.

I then pass this data to the class that interacts with the calendar. I am getting a compile time error where I am calling the function. Here is the error:

```
Instance members can't be accessed from a static method.
Try removing the reference to the instance member, or removing the keyword 'static' from the method.
```

As suggested in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69470420/instance-member-cant-be-accessed-using-static-access), I made an instance of the class.

Here is the code in the class where the error occurs:

```
class AddEventsToAllCalendars {
  static void addEvent(Events event) {
    Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal(buildEvent(event)); <<<  ERROR HERE
  }

  Event buildEvent(Events event) {
    Frequency freq = Frequency.yearly;

    if (event.frequency == 'daily') {
      freq = Frequency.daily;
    } else if (event.frequency == 'weekly') {
      freq = Frequency.weekly;
    } else if (event.frequency == 'monthly') {
      freq = Frequency.monthly;
    }

    return Event(
      title: event.eventName!,
      description: event.eventDescription,
      location: event.location,
      startDate: event.eventDate!,
      endDate: event.eventStartTime!
          .add(Duration(minutes: int.parse(event.eventDuration!))),
      allDay: event.allDay,
      recurrence: Recurrence(
        frequency: freq,
        endDate: event.recurrenceEndDate,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I correct this error?

Comment: You can’t call `buildEvent` from a static method, unless `buildEvent` is also static, or you create an instance of the class first to call it on

Comment: making buildEvent static solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to deal with static keyword (static modifier), should know the following.

function denoted by static modifier:

1. doesn't have access to (instance members).
2. doesn't have access to (this keyword).
3. can be called by `ClassName.methodName`.

class attribute (data member) denoted by static modifier:

1. is shared by all objects of that class
2. if it's value will not change, should be a static constant member.
3. all of the functions (static or instance) have access to static members.

after all, you should know, static variables can't be declared locally inside a method. it must be a class member.

according to your question, can be handled through:

1. making `buildEvent(event)` static method, so it can be called from another static.

or

2. make `addEvent(Events event)` an instance method, by removing static keyword.